# problema con manejo de ficheros en C

Tags: c

Estoy registrando datos en estructuras con manejo de ficheros, cuando registro los datos de los cursos y del profesor no me causa problemas,el problema es cuando deseo ingresar alumnos por que al leer el archivo, el nombre del primer alumno se sobrescribe en el nombre del profesor y no me imprime los datos de los demás alumnos.

estas son mis estructuras:

```
 struct estudiante{
    char matr[1];
};

struct profesor{
    int num;
};

struct persona{
    char nom[15];
    char ape[15];
    char apm[15];

    struct profesor prof;
    struct estudiante alumno;
};

typedef struct curso{
    int id;
    char ncurso[15];
};
```

esta es mi función para registrar datos:

```
void capdatos(){
FILE *fichero;
curso newcurso;
persona datos;
profesor prof;
estudiante alumno;

if ((fichero = fopen("fichero.txt","ab"))==NULL){
    printf("\nEl fichero no existe");
    system("pause");
}else{
//ingresando datos del curso    
    printf("\nID de la materia: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&newcurso.id);
    printf("\nEscribe el nombre del curso: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",newcurso.ncurso);
//ingresando datos del profesor
    printf("\nNumero deempleado del profesor: ");
    scanf("%d",&datos.prof.num);
    printf("\nNombre del profesor: ");  
    scanf("%s",datos.nom);
    printf("\nApellido del profesor: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",datos.ape);
    printf("\nApellido materno del profesor: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",datos.apm);
//ingresando alumnos al curso

estudiante *alum; 

printf("\nCuantos alumnos desea registrar en este curso: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

alum = (estudiante*)malloc(n*sizeof(estudiante));
if(alum == NULL){
    printf("\nError, memoria no reservada");
}if ((fichero = fopen("fichero.txt","ab"))==NULL){
    printf("\nEl fichero no existe");
    system("pause");
}else{
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    //alumno.matr=i+1;
    printf("\nNombre del alumno: ");    
    scanf("%s",datos.nom);
    printf("\nApellido paterno del alumno: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",datos.ape);
    printf("\nApellido materno del alumno: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",datos.apm);
   }
}   
    fwrite(&newcurso,sizeof(newcurso),1,fichero);
    fwrite(&datos,sizeof(datos),1,fichero);
    fclose(fichero);
}

}
```

me piden el uso de memoria dinámica para el registro de los alumnos. 
Espero y se entienda mi código y puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Solo tienes una variable `datos` en la que guardas primero los datos del profesor. Luego reservas memoria para un alumno, pero cuando pides datos los vuelves a guardar en la misma variable `datos` de antes, y la variable `alum` para la que has reservado memoria no la usas para nada. Tampoco liberas la memoria que reservas con `malloc`. Además, abres el fichero dos veces sin cerrarlo. Te recomiendo que depures y verás el problema de diseño más claro.

Comment: Gracias, lo checare. Pero cuando pido nuevamente datos, como podría guardarlos en la variable datos sin crear una nueva variable o estructura, es decir usar esa misma variable.

Comment: De ninguna manera. Si usas la misma variable para guardar los datos la segunda vez, obviamente pierdes el contenido que tenías antes. Tienes que guardar cada cosa en un sitio. Tienes que crear una variable del tipo persona para cada persona.